# Changing CSS styling based on what a link's HREF contains

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to search for any links that have an href of "#" and change the CSS styling of them to make those links a different color. Essentially, I want to be able to easily identify which links are broken and which aren't.

This is being used for a massive documentation project, and not all of the files are uploaded yet. I want users to be able to easily identify which links work and which won't. Is this able to be done with Javascript somehow?

Comment: suggest adding or changing class rather than inline style....far more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the links on the page, checking them individually and changing the style if required. Here's a starting point for you to expand from:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); //Get all the links
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) { //Loop through links
    if(anchors[i].href === '#') { //If link points to "href",
         anchors[i].style.color = 'red'; //then change the link's color to red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can do somehow like following:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.href === '#') {
       //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the **wrong approach**. You should probably have a server-side process that parses your files and fixes/identifies the broken links rather than doing it at runtime using JavaScript.

However, you can query elements based on their href attribute using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]'), function (link) {
    link.style.color = 'red'; //change style
});
```

Comment: @Jeffman You made me realize that I forgot this was a `NodeList`, not an array ;) forEach is a nice syntaxic sugar but is slower, however for a few iterations it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this question needs an answer that doesn't require JavaScript - styling links based on their href with pure CSS is much more efficient.

This CSS styles all links with an href of "#" red:

```
a[href="#"] {
    color: red;
}
```